# 64 bit assembly on Mac OS X runtime errors: "dyld: no writable segment" and "Trace/BPT trap"

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, att

When attempting to run the following assembly program:

```
.globl start

start:
    pushq $0x0 
    movq $0x1, %rax
    subq $0x8, %rsp
    int $0x80
```

I am receiving the following errors:

```
dyld: no writable segment
Trace/BPT trap
```

Any idea what could be causing this? The analogous program in 32 bit assembly runs fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OSX now requires your executable to have a writable data segment with content, so it can relocate and link your code dynamically. Dunno why, maybe security reasons, maybe due to the new RIP register. If you put a .data segment in there (with some bogus content), you'll avoid the "no writable segment" error. IMO this is an `ld` bug.

Regarding the 64-bit syscall, you can do it 2 ways. GCC-style, which uses the _syscall PROCEDURE from `libSystem.dylib`, or raw. Raw uses the `syscall` instruction, not the `int 0x80` trap. `int 0x80` is an illegal instruction in 64-bit.

The "GCC method" will take care of categorizing the syscall for you, so you can use the same 32-bit numbers found in sys/syscall.h. But if you go raw, you'll have to classify what kind of syscall it is by ORing it with a type id. Here is an example of both. Note that the calling convention is different! (this is `NASM` syntax because `gas` annoys me)

```
; assemble with
; nasm -f macho64 -o syscall64.o syscall64.asm && ld -lc -ldylib1.o -e start -o syscall64 syscall64.o
extern _syscall
global start

[section .text align=16]
start:
    ; do it gcc-style
    mov rdi, 0x4 ; sys_write
    mov rsi, 1 ; file descriptor
    mov rdx, hello
    mov rcx, size
    call _syscall ; we're calling a procedure, not trapping.
    
    ;now let's do it raw
    mov rax, 0x2000001 ; SYS_exit = 1 and is type 2 (bsd call)
    mov rdi, 0 ; Exit success = 0
    syscall ; faster than int 0x80, and legal!
    
    
[section .data align=16]
hello: db "hello 64-bit syscall!", 0x0a
size: equ $-hello
```

check out http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/osfmk/mach/i386/syscall_sw.h for more info on how a syscall is typed.

Comment: But I was under the impression syscalls were also able to be used in 32 bit assembly; what makes them mandatory in 64 bit? Is there any comparison between interrupts and syscalls to be found? Also would syscalls be found on other architectures or x86 only? I have a gut feeling syscalls are not a standard from what I have been able to find; to be clear I would like to have some knowledge I could use on PPC or ARM systems at some far off point in the future.

Comment: `lea rdx, [rel hello]` would be more efficient than a `mov` with a 64-bit immediate address.  And BTW, "illegal instruction" is the wrong term: That would means it doesn't even decode and raises a `#UD` exception.  (Like the [`ud2` instruction](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/UD).)  `int 0x80` will fault if the kernel decides it should, but it does decode and execute.  (And BTW, [Linux allows 64-bit processes to use the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/224132).  It's not generally useful and not recommended, though.)

Comment: You can and should still put your string in `section .rodata`, though, right?  Just just need an empty `.data` section?  Or do you need to have at least one byte in `.data` for NASM to emit one?

Answer (score 2):

The system call interface is different between 32 and 64 bits. Firstly, `int $80` is replaced by `syscall` and the system call numbers are different. You will need to look up documentation for a 64-bit version of your system call. [Here](http://thexploit.com/secdev/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls/) is an example of what a 64-bit program may look like.

Comment: you can use syscalls in 32 bit as well but I'm pretty sure the syscall is just a wrapper for the kernel interrupt. Any idea what the actual interrupt is or should I just start going through one-by-one?

Comment: Here's a list of OSX syscalls: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

Comment: but the syscall is wrapper for an interrupt, that's how it can invoke the kernel; maybe its not *recommended* but there must be a way to directly call the kernel interrupt in 64b

Comment: `syscall` is not a wrapper, if anything it is a more direct way to invoke the kernel.

Comment: How can it 'ask' the kernel to do something if not through an interrupt? The name sys**call** suggests it is a function/subroutine not that you are *call*ing, I thought to invoke the kernel you need to have the kernel run in its thread; how can calling something change the execution of the kernel if not through an interrupt?

Comment: You don't need interrupts to perform a system call, realy only save current instruction address and transfer control to the OS. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Typical_implementations and here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/system/article.php/c8223/System-Call-Optimization-with-the-SYSENTER-Instruction.htm

Comment: @Hawken: [`syscall` is a CPU instruction](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/SYSCALL) for fast system calls (i.e. switching to kernel mode (ring0) at an entry point the kernel configured earlier).  It works very much like a software-generated interrupt (`int $0x80`), but with a simpler faster implementation than the legacy interrupt mechanism.  e.g. it doesn't touch stack memory, it clobbers RCX and R11 with the saved RIP and RFLAGS values.