# Empty ASM program got signals

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm learning assembly and I'm trying to run a quite simple program.

```
section .text
    global start
    global _main

start:
    call _main
    ret

_main:
    push 42
    ret
```

I'm using NASM on OSX 64-bits. Here is what I tried :

```
$ nasm -f macho64 simple.asm -o simple.o
$ ld simple.o -o a.out
$ ./a.out
dyld: no writable segment
[1]    38021 trace trap  ./a.out
$
$ ld -lc -ldylib1.o -e start simple.o -o a.out
$ ./a.out
[1]    38134 segmentation fault  ./a.out
$
$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.8 -lSystem simple.o -o a.out
[1]    38134 segmentation fault  ./a.out
$
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882253/64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x-runtime-errors-dyld-no-writable-segment-and-tra), I added `section .data` into the code.

```
$ nasm -f macho64 simple.asm && ld simple.o && ./a.out
[1]    39119 killed     ./a.out
```

1) How can I get my program not to be killed ?

2) Why do my program get those signals (*SIGTRAP*, *SIGSEGV* and *SIGKILL*) ?

3) Where could I have found those answers without asking ? Explanations I've found until now do require prior knowledge about assembly.

**Edit**

I understood my mistake with `push 42`, thank you. My program runs when loaded with `ld -macosx_version_min 10.8 -lSystem simple.o`. But :

- I still have the SIGTRAP when loaded with `ld simple.o`
- I still have the segfault when loaded with `ld -lc -ldylib1.o -e start simple.o`
- I still have a SIGKILL when I add `section .data` and load with `ld simple.o`
- I have a bus error when I add `section .data` and load with `ld -macosx_version_min 10.8 -lSystem simple.o`

I wonder why I get those signals (in order to understand how it works). I'd also like to know why I have to specify `macosx_version_min` and how I could have found it without having a friend telling it to me.

Comment: `ret`, to quote the manual, "transfers program control to a return address located on the top of the stack." That would be 42.

Comment: Are you sure about SIGKILL?  If the entry point is in a non-executable page, I would have expected SIGSEGV (at least on Linux).  Try with `strace ./a.out` to trace system calls, including the `execve` that execs the file.  Also, run `gdb ./a.out`  (or `lldb`, or whatever debugger you prefer), and single-step through your code so you see what instruction faults and results in the kernel delivering a signal.

Comment: Also, your title is wrong.  Your program is most definitely not empty.  If it was, you'd just segfault from running the zero-padding as instructions, or SIGILL if execution hit some other bytes that didn't decode as valid instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How can I get my program not to be killed ?

It is not C: you don't `ret` that way. Your code is not called from a pre-established environment; what you should your `ret`urning to? By issuing such instruction, your `jmp`-ing to whatever value was on the stack currently at `%rsp` and going in a region potentially outside your process' address space, hence the SIGSEGV.

You have to explicitly tell the OS your process has terminated its execution through a system call.

Also, a ELF's starting point is usually `_start`, not `start`, which you should otherwise indicate to the linker.

> I still have the segfault when loaded with ld -lc -ldylib1.o -e start simple.o

**Don't** link with C, unless you're conforming to its execution model. Also I don't understand what you mean by "load with ld file.o".

Comment: If `ld` doesn't find a symbol called `_start`, it defaults to the beginning of the text segment.

Comment: @PeterCordes I made a pretty much strong assertion by saying an ELF's starting point is `_start`, I don't know whether that's mandatory (doubt so) or not. I mean, `ld` does that - but if I wrote my linker, could I refuse to link?

Comment: Yeah, of course.  If you don't care about command-line compatibility with `ld`, your linker can do anything you want.  Like I said, `ld`'s actual behaviour is to fall back to the start of the .text section:  *ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400080*.  You can also use `ld -e symbol_name` to set a symbol name it will look for instead of `_start`.  So even in a non-stripped binary linked by `ld`, it's not totally safe to assume that the entry point is `_start`.  To reliably set a breakpoint there when debugging it, use `readelf -a` to find the numeric address

Comment: I will say it's a rather risky decision: just having `.text \n .word 0xf0b \n entry: # your code` will be source of long debugging sessions, if you forget that `-e entry`. That constant will be guiltless-looking, but it's not.

Comment: I didn't say any of that was a good idea, I just explained `ld`'s actual behaviour, which some build systems might rely on.  It's usually a terrible idea to use `-e` instead of just calling your entry point `_start` like a normal person.  Even worse is if you *have* a `_start` symbol but it's not the entry point.  `b _start` will set a breakpoint there, but it won't be the first code to execute!

Comment: @PeterCordes: Absolutely, just a free thought I found worthy pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Your *main* problem is simple. In your short program you are pushing the value 42 on the stack immediately before the [`RET`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html) pops it to jump to it - which causes a `segfault`, because it jumps to the address `00000042`(32-bit-mode), which (in protected mode) causes most likely an exception.